# word replacement macro in excel does not work

Tags: excel, vba, replace, ms-word

I'm trying to input my Excel results into a pre made Word document.
I want to use a macro for this. I'm fairly new to the code writing game but I understand the basics.
I tried to copy from different courses but none of them works.

This simple macro should change 'x1' into 'anything',
but all it does for me is open the document and select the x1 in the document.

Does anyone know where I go wrong?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    wrdApp.Visible = True
    Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Open("C:\Users\mycomputer\Documents\PremadeDocument.docx")

        wrdApp.Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
        wrdApp.Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With wrdApp.Selection.Find
        .Text = "x1"
        .Replacement.Text = "anything"
    '    .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    '    .Format = False
    '    .MatchCase = False
    '    .MatchWholeWord = False
    '    .MatchWildcards = False
    '    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    '    .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
        wrdApp.Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

    Set wrdDoc = Nothing
    Set wrdApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Not sure but would it be wrdDoc.selection etc instead of wrdApp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add [Word Enumerated Const](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa211923(v=office.11).aspx) value for wdReplaceAll

```
Const wdReplaceAll = 2
```

After the Macro definition

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Const wdReplaceAll = 2
```